# How to disable panning of X11 with a screen larger than the connected output without shrinking the screen?

Tags: linux, nvidia, x11

Hi crowd intelligence,

I'm trying to configure my X11 server on a ubuntu 18.04 server in a way, so I can have a larger virtual screen than my connected output without having the output in panning mode. My system is running with an nvidia gpu.

Perfect would be, if I could achieve this programmatically.

Looking into the RandR protocol, I found that there is a method XRRSetPanning which should be able to disable panning for a certain CRTC when the `x` and `y` value are set to zero. This should be identical to what is executed when I call `xrandr --output $MyOutput --panning 0x0`.

The issue is, that when I do this, I get a BadValue error.

When trying to call `xrandr --fb 3000x4000 --output $MyOutput --panning 1920x1080` and the output is `1920x1080` as well, I also get a BadValue. When calling `xrandr --fb 3000x4000 --output $MyOutput --panning 1920x1200` the screen size gets adopted to `1920x1200` as well, which is what I don't want. I would have expected that in all cases, the screen stays `3000x4000` and that the panning is set correctly without errors...

Interesting enough, I saw this working on another machine before, so I think there is a way around it.

Having digged a bit deeper, I found, that this seems to be a feature of the nvidia driver called [TwinView](https://http.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/325.15/README/configtwinview.html) I suppose.
I think, that I have to disable this feature in order to achieve my intentions... The question is how... And this is where I hope that you can help me.

Comment: I don't have any idea how to do what I think you want, but I don't really understand your question. It sounds like you want a virtual screen resolution of 3000x4000, while the physical resolution is limited to 1920x1080. So you have a big chunk of off-screen virtual real-estate that you cannot reach. Is that a fair summary?

Comment: Hi @James, really sorry for coming back late. That is exactly what I want to do. Since I want to have a streaming application that acts like an additional monitor placed beside the physical one on the virtual screen. The streaming app than observes that "unreachable" portion of the virtual screen.

Comment: However, I found a workaround for now. I enable a second physical output by force within the xorg.conf and place it in a way that it "stretches" the virtual screen to the size I want... But if anyone has a better solution for this challenge, I am curious to try / learn...